# common element of subgroups of $p-$group $G$ and generator set of $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider a $p-$group $G$ and a set $S$ which generates $G$ and $|S|>5$. (I can consider the case that $S$ is minimal) consider an arbitrary non trivial subgroup $H$ of $G$. It s clear that there are some cyclic subgroups $H$ that $|H\cap S|<|S|$. I need some subgroups of $G$ that they have not any common element with $S$. Is there such kind of subgroup exist? Or is there any way to design a subgroup of $G$ with at least common word with $S$?

Comment: Have you heard about the Frattini subgroup?

Comment: Yes I knew the definition and I got the point, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be proper subgroup of $G$ then set $S=G-H$ then $<S>=G$.

it is enough to show that elements of $H$ can be constructed by elements of $S$.
Nottice that $hs\in S$ for $h\in H$ and $s\in S$ since if $hs \in H \implies s\in H$ which is a contradiction.
Thus, $hs\in S \implies h=s^{-1}s_2$ $\implies<S>=G$.

Thus for any proper subgroup $H$ of $G$,we have a generating set $S$  s.t $H\cap S=\emptyset$

I hope this is what you need.